# why string swap not allowed in this case

Tags: c++, string

I have a function

```
void foo(string *input) {
    string temp = "";
    input->swap(&temp);
}
```

But this seems not working... I guess the reason is temp is a temporal var
so will be de-allocated as we leave this function?

Comment: I don't advise using pointers when you can use references instead.

Comment: "Temporal Var" sounds like a bad Stargate episode.

Comment: Easier: `string().swap(*input);`

Answer (score 3):

The [`swap()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/swap) member function of `std::string` accepts a reference, not a pointer:

```
input->swap(temp);
```

Also, I would suggest you taking the Standard Library's example, and letting your `foo()` function also accept a reference rather than a pointer:

```
void foo(string& input) {
    string temp = "";
    input.swap(temp);
}
```